# set the default jdk for maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, maven

I have just installed maven on an new ubuntu system, which includes the maven-compiler-plugin. I have a java project that was previously building fine, defaulting to a javac source and target of 5 (jdk 1.5). However, the project is now trying to compile using jdk1.3 on the new system. Is there an easy way to configure the system to use >=jdk5  ?

Here's some of the configuration details of the system:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"

$ dpkg -s maven
Package: maven
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: java
Installed-Size: 1489
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Version: 3.0.4-2

$ dpkg -s libmaven-compiler-plugin-java
Package: libmaven-compiler-plugin-java
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: java
Installed-Size: 75
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Source: maven-compiler-plugin
Version: 2.0.2-6
```

I've checked the maven-compiler-plugin-2.0.2.pom file, and plexus-compiler-javac.originalVersion and others are set to 1.5.3.

I know I can set this on a per-project basis by including a source/target tag in a plugin context, but I'd like to configure maven-compiler to default to jdk5 or higher without having to do this across a large number of projects.

how can i do this?

Comment: Did you set the java compiler version in the pom.xml of your project? Try this http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: Isn't that a very old version of maven-compiler-plugin?

Comment: I always set it per project as its far safer. If you were to update the jvm level then you'd still need to check each project over.

Comment: $ mvn compile -V
Apache Maven 3.0.4
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_45, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.2.0-35-virtual", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

Comment: with regards to setting compiler version in the pom.xml of my project: "I know I can set this on a per-project basis by including..." in my original question, but we have a large number of projects, and I don't want to have to maintain the compiler plugin across all of them. Would like to configure it to work out the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default value for source and target was 1.3 in older versions of maven-compiler plugin (like 2.0.2-6).
Use at least a 3.0 version of the Maven compiler plugin to get this back to the original behaviour, or just configure that plugin to get source and target to appropriate values.

Answer (score 19):

In your pom specify the following to set the compiler to JDK5:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

i.e.

```
<project>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    ...
  </project>
```

I specify mine prior to the dependencies, although so long as its part of the project element you should be able to place it anywhere inside the pom.

I ran into a similar issue with Maven previously, this fixed it for me. Essentially what this does is set the `-source` and `-target` flags to the value specified and passes it to the compiler. Newer plugins default to 1.5.

In order to use the default approach *without* specifying the properties, you will need to be running a later version of Maven.

I suppose you could also set up a template via your IDE to include this in all new pom files. Of course the actual implementation would depend upon your IDE...

See [The apache maven compiler plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) as well as [Setting the source and compiler examples](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) for more details.

Answer (score 8):

I tried the **maven-compiler-plugin** approach and it proved cumbersome as there are plugins like **maven-surefire-plugin** and **maven-cobertura-plugin** which still fail due to incompatibility issues.

The better approach was to use [maven-toolchain-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html).

**Step 1**
Create **/.m2/toolchains.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<toolchains>
<!-- JDK toolchains -->
<toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <vendor>sun</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
          <jdkHome>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
</toolchain>
<toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <vendor>sun</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
        <jdkHome>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
</toolchain>
<toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <vendor>apple</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
        <jdkHome>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_65-b14-462.jdk/Contents/Home</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
</toolchain>

<!-- other toolchains -->
<!--
<toolchain>
    <type>netbeans</type>
    <provides>
        <version>5.5</version>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
        <installDir>/path/to/netbeans/5.5</installDir>
    </configuration>
</toolchain>
-->
```

**Step 2**
Add **maven-toolchain-plugin** to **plugins** section in your project **pom.xml**.

*If using maven 3, ensure this goes into **pluginManagement** as well *

```
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>toolchain</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <toolchains>
                    <jdk>
                        <version>1.7</version>
                        <vendor>sun</vendor>
                    </jdk>
                </toolchains>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Voila all your other plugins pick up the right **JDK**. Hope it helps. I spent almost half day on this exact issue today.

Answer (score 1):

I used following settings to set maven default java compiler version.

first, modify maven settings.xml:

```
<profile>
  <id>jdk-1.8</id>
  <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      <jdk>1.8</jdk>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.compilerVersion>1.8</maven.compiler.compilerVersion>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

second, in eclipse preferences, make the java home point to jdk home

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Use the latest maven compiler plugin.

In order to change the defaults, you should set source and target.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

More Info: [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Comment: From my original post:

"I know I can set this on a per-project basis by including a source/target tag in a plugin context, but I'd like to configure maven-compiler to default to jdk5 or higher without having to do this across a large number of projects."

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to such things is using an up-to-date version of Maven (3.1.1) and in particular create a parent pom.xml file for all your projects where you define the configuration and version of your maven-compiler-plugin via pluginManagement or better all of your plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Chinto's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204292/chinto) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28038476/845117) I got it running on my windows machine with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
<toolchains>
  <!-- JDK toolchains -->
  <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <version>1.8</version>
      <vendor>openjdk</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <jdkHome>C:\path\to\openJDK1.8.0</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
</toolchains>
```